# I get a ServiceForbiddenException when I try to connect to a Youtube account via the Java Youtube Data Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, youtube, google-data-api

I'm trying to learn the Google Data Api for Youtube and I've installed the Google Data Api Plugin for Eclipse.

When I try to run a simple "Hello World" project using the Google Data Project wizard (for Youtube to be more exact) I'm getting a ServiceForbiddenException.

The code looks like this:

```
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This is a test template
 */

  public class YouTube {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        // Create a new YouTube service
        YouTubeService myService = new YouTubeService("My Application");

        // Get a list of all entries
       // URL metafeedUrl = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+args[0]+"/favorites");

        URL metafeedUrl = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Sebastian/favorites");

        System.out.println("Getting favorite video entries...\n");

        VideoFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(metafeedUrl, VideoFeed.class);
        List<VideoEntry> entries = resultFeed.getEntries();
        for(int i=0; i<entries.size(); i++) {
          VideoEntry entry = entries.get(i);
          System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
        }
        System.out.println("\nTotal Entries: "+entries.size());
      }
      catch(AuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the sample code that comes from the project wizard. The only modification I've done is to hardcode my youtube username (Sebastian) inside the URL:

```
 URL metafeedUrl = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Sebastian/favorites");
```

but I receive the following exception

```
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: Not allowed.
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceForbiddenException</code><internalReason>Not allowed.</internalReason></error></errors>

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:605)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
    at YouTube.main(YouTube.java:44)
```

Frankly, I'm not sure that my "username" is really "Sebastian" (as it seems to me that it is highly unusual to be only one account with this name). I've also tried changing the above URL with my email address (thinking this is the actual "username" for my youtube account since I allways log in by using my email address) as the username but this time I  get another exception that looks like this:

```
com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Invalid value for parameter: username
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>InvalidRequestUriException</code><internalReason>Invalid value for parameter: username</internalReason></error></errors>

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:602)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
    at YouTube.main(YouTube.java:44)
```

How can I get this program to work and to list my favorite youtube videos? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've managed to solve this problem. The issue was that I didn't specify the correct username. Neither my password nor "Sebastian" (my name) were my real username for my youtube account.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem. The issue was that I didn't specify the correct username. Neither my email address nor "Sebastian" (my name) were my real username for my youtube account.

I've managed to find the real username of my account by examining the url of the page of my youtube channel page. (by the way, this works for every user's channel not only yours)

So the url was looking like this :
https://www.youtube.com/user/myusername

where instead of the "myusername" part was my real username for my youtube account.

le: I have checked this again and in order for your browser to display that url you have to click on the actual title on your channel's main page. (so go to your channel's main page and click on the big title on that page; i.e. the one that shows your channel name)